# Trying to expose collection as array in custom object

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to do something like this:

`json.Properties["ssn"].Value = ...;`

The code behind this looks like so:

```
public JsonProperty this[String name]
{
    get
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Properties.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.Properties[i].Name.Equals(name))
            {
                return Properties[i];
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentNullException("No property with that name exists");
    }
    set
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Properties.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.Properties[i].Name.Equals(name))
            {
                this.Properties[i].Value = value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Intellisense is giving me an error though on this line: `this.Properties[i].Value = value;`

It tells me the following:

`Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.List<...>.this[int]' because it is not a variable.`

I am not exactly sure how to solve this. Any advise?

Comment: `this.Properties[i] = value;` ??

Comment: @CarbineCoder Would be easier if you just asked me about that line instead of doing that.

Comment: What framework you using for Json?

Comment: You might want to consider using a Dictionary instead of a List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already answered to your question. You can not modify struct members directly

What you need to do is to create new JsonPropetry and assign to Properties list

```
Properties[i] = new JsonProperty(name, value);//don't know exact JsonProperty constructor
```

or

```
 JsonProperty temp = Properties[i];
 temp.Value = value;
 Properties[i] = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the architecture of the `JsonProperty` class,
but it seems that you are trying to input the RHS form the indexer `JsonProperty` into
`Properties[i].Value` (which is `JsonProperty.Value` and not just `JsonProperty`).

Try changing the line to:

```
this.Properties[i] = value;
```

or (and this would be wrong for an indexer IMO)

```
this.Properties[i].Value = value.Value;
```

Comment: The JsonProperty is just a struct with two strings in it. Name and Value. I want to be able to just use the [] operator on my object to find the value of a JsonProperty.

Comment: Still, the setter will take in a `JsonProperty` on the RHS of the equation, not a string.